# HttpClient.excute(HttpPost) no response

Tags: java, http, rest

I constructed an HttpClient, and set timeout parameters.

the code is like this:

```
while(bufferedinputstream.read()!=-1){

    post.setEntity(multipartEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.excute(post);
}
```

it worked fine for the first several request, and then somehow the response is not returned, and no exception or timeout exception was thrown. Anyone has any idea what's happening?

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java

Comment: Is the request reaching the server? did u check your server logs

Comment: is anything printed in logcat?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I couldn't get the server logs at present. But what if the request reached the server? All previous packages reached the server, what's the reason that one of the package couldn't reach server?

Comment: @Julie You never know, the server may be just getting slower and slower with requests before giving up :-)

Answer (score -1):

since you re not getting any errors or exceptions (do you print them out?), you could check the satusCode of your response. Maybe it helps.

(overridden method from my AsyncTask)

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
    String url = arg[0]; // Added this line
    //...

    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "URL CALL -> " + url);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    String mResponse = "";
    try {

         List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
         //...

         post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse mHTTPResponse = client.execute(post);

        StatusLine statusLine = mHTTPResponse.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200) { // 

            //get response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    mHTTPResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String aux = "";

            while ((aux = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(aux);
            }

            mResponse = builder.toString();

        } else {
            //cancel task and show error
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "ERROR in Request:" + statusCode);
            this.cancel(true);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mResponse;
}
```

Comment: I should check the status code of the response object, only if the response object is returned. However, the response object was never returned from this line: response = client.excute(post);

Comment: yes, and you don't know why. that's why i suggested you should check your stausCode from the response, since you don't get any errors...

Comment: but the code stays on: ' response = client.excute(post) ' , the program doesn't really go down

Comment: mmh... than you eiter should post more information or monitor your network traffic with charles proxy for example. usually i could detect at least at this point, why there's nothing responded